# Feature Request - Dataset formatter

Tags: feature-request

I am active on the Python tag and most of the questions there are related to the [Pandas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_%28software%29) library. Most of the time, these questions are related to a dataset. However, a few questions have a sample of a dataset attached to the Python code and is directly usable.

Isn't it possible to add something in the toolbar which could open a dataset editor where you can copy some data from your studied dataset or where you can manually edit it?

Then it would generate the related code to generate (for the person who desire to answer) a Pandas dataframe.

Comment: This has traditionally been delegated to external sites. There are too many different kinds of data formats, with too many evolving tools for SO to be able to keep up. E.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/ for databases, or regex101 for regular expressions.

Comment: For Pandas, there is advice here: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](//stackoverflow.com/q/20109391), which helps you format the example such that answerers can use `pd.read_clipboard()` to recreate it locally.

Comment: Then i guess the community should be more strict about adding sample as it is described in your link

Comment: *"most of the question there are related to Pandas library"*. Not really. Currently, there are 133,908 questions tagged with pandas, but 1,216,464 questions tagged with python but not pandas. Of course, there are also many Pandas question without the tag, but there are also many Python questions that don't have the generic python tag, just a version tag like python-3.x or python-2.7

Comment: @Clément "_Then i guess the community should be more strict ..._": absolutely! All the "I have some data that maybe looks like this and I might want to turn it into something like that [insert image with hand drawing]" questions should be closed on sight, but due to a handful of users in the tag who will answer literally anything moderation of the tag is hopeless. I've considered it a wasteland for a while. If you see such a question: downvote, close vote, close the tab. You're only getting yourself worked up for no reason otherwise.

Answer (score 7):

Please don't do this. The `pandas` tag is already a mess and actually really difficult to organise. While, in principle, this would be a fantastic feature, it's almost certainly going to result in people becoming more lazy. I know from the Python chat room that people actively avoid the tag already because it's scatter-gun as it is.

The specifics of what you're asking for are actually very unclear but, it seems essentially, that it boils down to facilitating the dumping of datasets to be reproduced.

One point that was raised in the chat room was that there is no reason for `pandas` to be special-cased here. I totally agree with that; there's plenty of languages that process data and any implementation would have to be mindful of all of them.

Secondly, it's *easy enough* to create repeatable data sets. There's nothing stopping people from posting a self-building dataframe to illustrate a problem. A recent example was raised in chat about datetime formatting and I just built my own example to start tackling the problem:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2012/03/05', '2012/03/04', '04/03/2012', '03/04/2012'],
                   'format': ['YYYY/MM/DD', 'YYYY/MM/DD', 'DD/MM/YYYY', 'DD/MM/YYYY']})
```

I'm having to translate words to an example but there was *nothing stopping them bringing that example to the table* at the start. There is purpose in producing MCVEs because it tends to get rid of the simple cases and makes you think more deeply about the problem. If you find that your MCVE needs to tackle a huge number of *distinct* cases then the issue is probably upstream.

The emphasis should be on making people think twice about their examples and not just dumping problems.